# Why: Python 'Import x' then Re- 'import x as y' clobbers import of x?

Tags: python, nosetests, python-unittest

So, I have a small Python import mystery.  I'm confident it's supposed to be this way for some reason, since Guido is seldom wrong.  But, why is it so?

```
$ cat myModule.py
#!/usr/bin/python

class SomeModule(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print "in SomeModule.__init__ ! "

    def doSomething(self):
        print 'doing something.'

$ cat myTest.py
import unittest
from myModule import SomeModule

class TestMyModule(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_001(self):
        print "should see init below"
        sm = SomeModule()
        sm.doSomething()
        print "should see init above\n"

    def test_002(self):
        print "should not see init below."
        from myModule import SomeModule as SM2
        SM2.__init__ = lambda x: None
        sm2 = SM2()
        sm2.doSomething()
        print "should not have seen init above.\n"

    def test_bbb(self):
        print "Should see init below"
        sm = SomeModule()
        sm.doSomething()
        print "should see init above\n"

$ nosetests myTest.py -s
should see init below
in SomeModule.__init__ ! 
doing something.

should see init above
.should not see init below.
doing something.
should not have seen init above.

.Should see init below
doing something.
should see init above
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

The final test should be unaffected by the middle tests's import, right?  My intuition says I don't have to worry about the initial import since the second import uses an 'as'.  **Thus, in the last test, I expect to see the init but I do not.**

Apparently, the second import, the 'from myModule import SomeModule as SM2', clobbers the initial import of Some Module, even though it seems like it should be a completely independent entity as SM2, not SomeModule.

Does this make sense to someone?

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" here is that `SM2` and `SomeModule` are the **same class**. In python, there's only a single "instance" of each module - reimporting will return a reference to the same object:

```
>>> import code
>>> import code as code2
>>> code is code2
True
```

In your code, when you run `SM2.__init__ = lambda x: None`, you're replacing the constructor of the class. This affects `SM2`, `SomeModule`, and also *any other code that may have imported from `myModule`*.

The same thing would happen if you simply aliased the class with `SM2= SomeModule`.

It's also the same mechanism that makes new programmers surprised when they start handling lists and expect assigning to a new variable to copy the actual list:

```
>>> a=[1]
>>> b=a
>>> b.append(2)
>>> print a
[1, 2]
```

You can verify *identity* of your objects in your code by using `is`. Note this is not the same as *equality*:

```
>>> []==[]
True
>>> [] is []
False
```

Comment: `this has nothing whatsoever to do with imports` - It comes from a misunderstanding of how Python deals with imports, a reasonable expectation that comes from other languages:  We think it'll read from the filesystem each time, instead of pull from `sys.modules` (which AFAIK isn't well-documented).  Before doing the digging, what we expect is more akin to a `json.loads()` (essentially a deep copy) than just assigning a list to a second variable

Comment: @Izkata you're right, I failed to consider that the behaviour of `import` may not be obvious to a new python user. I've edited the question to explain this